# Reading from a .txt while inside a class

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error

> is a field but is used as a type.

I've looked around here and tried putting it outside of the class like

```
private string[] patron = new line.Split(':');

public void readTxt()//method for reading info from a txt
{
    idNum = Convert.ToInt32(patron[0]);
    fName = patron[1];
    lName = patron[2];
    address = patron[3];
    city = patron[4];
    state = patron[5];
    zip = patron[6];
    emailAddress = patron[7];
    phoneNum = patron[8];
}
```

But that doesn't work either. I've also had it inside the method and received the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: What this code supposed to do: `new line.Split(':');`? It will not be compiled either.

Answer (score 8):

This is the problem:

```
new line.Split(':');
```

That makes it look like you're trying to create an instance of a type called `line` (although without specifying any arguments).

You just want:

```
private string[] patron = line.Split(':');
```

... although doing that in an instance variable initializer is unlikely to work unless `line` is a static variable. That sounds like something that should be done in a constructor, or a method.

Indeed, given the name of your method, it sounds like you should be reading the value *in* your method (from the file) and then splitting it:

```
public void ReadText()
{
    string line = ...; // However you read a line
    string[] patron = line.Split(':');
    idNum = patron[0];
    ...
}
```

Or you could put that in the constructor for your type, e.g.

```
public Person(string line)
{
    string[] patron = line.Split(':');
    idNum = patron[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: So you're saying I should read the line into a variable and then split it? Instead of doing the reading and splitting through the patron array?

Comment: @BillBishop: I don't understand your comment. I assume that `line` is *already* a variable - my suggestion is that you split that, saving the results in a variable called `patron`. How is that "instead of [...] splitting through the patron array"?

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your solution. I did just realize what the issue was. I have the textreader code not inside the class. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

the Split function returns a string array, you don't have to put the keyword "new" in front of it.

So, put that line inside your method readTXt() (if you dont' need the array in other parts of your code) and correct the line in this way:

```
string[] patron = line.Split(':');
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Doing this does remove the compiler error but when I run it, I get an exception saying object reference not set to an instance of the object. But doesn't that line is creating the instance isn't it?